# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

Tags: javascript

Any ideas what this error is about?

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

```
   function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
        return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
    }
```

Comment: Browser? Browser Version?

Comment: Does the browser you are using support arrow functions?

Comment: guessing the browser you are using doesnt support fat arrow functions

Comment: It's an old iPad that gives that message. How can I fix it? Thx

Comment: @SeaBass You can compile it with Babel: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @SeaBass Don't use arrow functions and other ES6 features, or transpile your code.

Comment: use [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) seem to not be supported by your environment (Browser, Node, etc.). Try using a regular anonymous function:

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(function(key) { return object[key] === value; });
}
```

Or use a transpiler, such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which allows you to use newer versions of JavaScript that support arrow functions.